# Convergence of $c^* Ac$ in second quantization

Tags: hilbert-space, operators, mathematical-physics, second-quantization

Let $A$ denote a bounded operator on a complex separable Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$. Let $\mathscr{F} = \bigoplus \mathscr{F}_N$ be the Fock space generated by $\mathscr{H}$ where $\mathscr{F}_N$ is the $N$-particle Hilbert space. Let $d\Gamma (A):\mathscr{F}_N \to \mathscr{F}_N$ be defined as
$$d\Gamma (A) =A\otimes I\otimes \cdots \otimes I+\cdots+I\otimes\cdots\otimes I\otimes A$$
so that (restricted to $\mathscr{F}_N$) is bounded linear (i.e., we don't have to worry about domain problems). In physics, we usually use creation and annihilation operators to represent $d\Gamma (A)$, i.e.,
$$
c^* Ac \equiv\sum_nc^*(A \varphi_n)c(\varphi_n) =\sum_{m,n} A_{mn} c_m^* c_n
$$
where $\varphi_n =|n\rangle$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathscr{H}$.

**Question**. What kind of convergence does $c^* Ac$ have relative to $d\Gamma (A)$, i.e., in what topology does $\sum_{n\le N} c^*(A \varphi_n)c(\varphi_n) \to d\Gamma (A)$ as $N\to \infty$?

**EDIT**. Of course, if $\mathscr{H}$ is finite-dim, then the summation is finite and the 2 are equal. However, in infinite-dim, the best that I can do is that if $g$ is in the span of pure tensors in $\mathscr{F}^N$, then
$$
c^*Ac|g\rangle
$$
is well-defined and equal to $d\Gamma(A)|g\rangle$. This seems very close to strong-operator topology convergence, but not quite. Maybe there's a way to make this stronger?

Comment: Is the dimension of $\mathscr{F}$ equal to the direct sum of all dimensions of the $\mathscr {H}_N$, the dimensions of the $N$-particle Hilbert spaces?

Comment: Almost. Since we are considering a Fock space, we need to symmetrize/anti-symmetrize each tensor product $\mathscr{H}^{\otimes N}$, which corresponds to a projection operator. For example, for fermions (anti-symmetrization), $\mathscr{F}$ would have dimension $2^n$ where $n$ is the dimension of $\mathscr{H}$